# Cannot clone git repository does not appear to be a git repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git

I'm following git's doc to cretae a repository on a remote server 
on the local pc :

```
$ git clone --bare my_project my_project.git
```

I've copied the repository on the server

```
$ scp -r my_project.git myuser@myip:/opt/git
```

but if I try to clone

```
git clone myuser@myip:/opt/git/my_project.git
```

I get

```
fatal: 'opt/git/my_project.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I though that it was a permission problem ,but if I connect with `ssh myuser@myip` I have no problem to create files o do anything ,the folder belongs to myuser.

Comment: This syntax would appear to work for me (even though the `scp` instead of `git push` is a bit odd way to go about it). But if you look at your error message, not the missing leading `/`. For (some reason unclear to me) `git` is look for `opt/git/my_project.git` relative to home of `myuser` and not `/opt/git/my_project.git` where it is. In other words, I must be missing a bit. Version? Perhaps try to prefix `myuser` with `ssh://` scheme in case something in the name was causing trouble?

Comment: Thank you but I already solved it

Comment: In that case, you may want to share your findings for sake of the future readers.

Answer (score 1):

First, check that your **origin** is set by running

```
git remote -v
```

This should show you all of the push / fetch remotes for the project.

*If this returns with no output, skip to last code block.*

**Verify remote name / address**

If this returns showing that you have remotes set, check that the name of the remote matches the remote you are using in your commands.

```
$git remote -v
myOrigin ssh://git@example.com:1234/myRepo.git (fetch)
myOrigin ssh://git@example.com:1234/myRepo.git (push)

# this will fail because `origin` is not set
$git push origin master

# you need to use
$git push myOrigin master
```

If you want to rename the remote or change the remote's URL, you'll want to first remove the old remote, and then add the correct one.

**Remove the old remote**

```
$git remote remove myOrigin
```

**Add missing remote**

You can then add in the proper remote using

```
$git remote add origin ssh://git@example.com:1234/myRepo.git

# this will now work as expected
$git push origin master
```